# Image move and scale issue in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5

Recently i have upgraded my iphone to iOS5 . After upgrade to iOS 5, the usual move and scale on the image is not working ( UImagePickerController ).

In the iOs 5 , only after zooming the image, i can able to move and scale the image. But the same functionality was working in iOS 4.2.1. I mean without zooming the image , i was able to move and scale  while editing the image.

Also when i check the "Contacts" app in iOS 5 for adding a photo for new contact , I was not able to move and scale the image without zooming.

Is this a apple ios5 bug or anyway to accomplish move and scale functionality.

So Please anyone help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the way it works now. Adapt.

Comment: I have seen this same issue, but have not found a solution or an explanation for why it works this way now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move and scale is not working for me either. But I found a way around. I used the new 'crop' feature inside the photo app. If you want to move down, crop the photo from the bottom, if you want to move up, crop the photo from the top. Then save it and use it a wallpaper. Hope this helps.

You can also use the zooming feature. zoom it little bit and then go back to the actual size. then you will be able to move the image.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, once we zooming only it will allow to crop. Is there any chance before zooming for crop?.